# Excel Power Query. Run multiple queries by list of templates to join tables in different files

Tags: excel, odbc, powerquery

I have a question:
I have 60+ tables in dbf with columns: year, product, value. Tables have different years data.

EXAMPLE.

```
Table 1
Year  product value
1993     Apple  98.45
1994   Mushrooms 67.54

Table 2
Year  product value
1992  Apple  95.45
2021  Melon 112.0
```

I need a pivot table(to consolidate) all tables in one table.

My way:

```
Let
DatesList={1992, 1993,1994,1995,2021},
Tbl=Odbc.Query("dsn=my_custom_dsn", "select * from c:\data\1993.dbf"),
Result=List.Accumulate (DatesList, Tbl, (state, current) =>Table.Join(Tbl, "product", Query.odbc("dsn=my_custom_dsn", "select * from c:\data\" +Text.From(current) +".dbf", "product")

in
 Result
```

Its ok, but results only for the last date. How to save Table between dates

Please, help

Comment: I'm not sure how your code will do anything since your line2 (`DatesList=`) is not valid PQ syntax.

Comment: Ok, I have shortened the code. I have corrected the DatesList.

Comment: How can I save temporary Table.Join results in List.Accumulate. I suppose I have to create a function, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are overcomplicating.

Try this:

```
let
      DatesList = Table.FromList({1992,1993,1994,1995,2021}, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), {"Year"}, null, ExtraValues.Error)
    , #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(DatesList, "Data", each Odbc.Query("dsn=my_custom_dsn", "select * from c:\data\" & Number.ToText([Year]) & ".dbf"))
    , #"Expanded Data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom", "Data", {"product", "table"}, {"product", "table"})
in
    #"Expanded Data"
```

Remember in your question you misspelled `Odbc.Query`

Comment: Thank you. I have written it using the mobile phone, so - errors. In real code its ok. Well, a nice solution.

Comment: Michal, if we imagine, that years list is a list of codes. And I have a list of pseudo formulas I have to calculate: e. g., 1994-1993,1993/1992*100-100,... A list of 65 formulas. How would you make this calculation? Can you help, please?

Comment: I do not think I follow. Is this related with your question? If not then it will be better to create new question and give better explanation of the problem  (with an example). :)

Comment: Michal, I posted a new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66090912/excel-power-query-different-formulas-for-each-row-of-values-from-other-rows . Please, kindly have a look. Thank you!