# Excel Power Query. Different Formulas for Each Row of Values from Other Rows

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a table 1 of 500+ rows that are updated multiple times during a month by a request.
And there is a updated table of different formulas (200+) that should be calculated using values from table 1.

Table 1

| year | product | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1993 | Apple | 98.45 |
| 1994 | Mushrooms | 67.54 |
| 1992 | Apple | 95.45 |
| 2021 | Melon | 112.0 |

Table 2

| id | formula |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1994/1993*100-100 |
| 2 | 1994-1993 |
| 3 | 2021/1992*100-100 |

etc...

**My way:**

1. in table_1 I have created a key column - year.
2. I have modified the formula (below - a pic):

[image: table_2]

Code for table_2:

```
   let
        src = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="table_2"]}[Content],
        pq_auto1 = Table.PromoteHeaders(src, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
        pq_auto2 = Table.TransformColumnTypes(pq_auto1,{{"Id", Int64.Type}, {"formula", type text}}),
        result = Table.AddColumn(pq_auto2,"value",each Expression.Evaluate([modified_formula],#shared))
   in
        result
```

Can you suggest me to find a better way to do this calculations by each row?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to do that just like with Excel formula however [BI Accountant](https://www.thebiccountant.com/2018/07/12/fast-and-easy-way-to-reference-previous-or-next-rows-in-power-query-or-power-bi/) showed elegant solution by shifting column by one row:

[image]

```
let
     Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content]
    ,ShiftedList = {null} & List.RemoveLastN(Table.Column(Source, "ColumnToBeShifted"), 1)
    ,NewShiftedColumn = Table.FromColumns(Table.ToColumns(Source) & {ShiftedList}, Table.ColumnNames(Source) & {"NewColumnName"})
in
    NewShiftedColumn
```

With this your calculation should be very easy.